# AWS RDS keeps backing up my server on creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, amazon-rds

I am using Amazon CloudFormation to create a Stack with EC2 and RDS (Postgres 9.4.4, 5gb, db.m1.small). The RDS instance initiates a backup as soon as it starts.

How can I stop RDS from backing it up at startup?

Here is the Postgres log:

```
2016-01-12 22:23:31 UTC::@:[2435]:LOG: database system is ready to accept connections
2016-01-12 22:23:31 UTC::@:[2448]:LOG: autovacuum launcher started
2016-01-12 22:23:34 UTC::@:[2445]:LOG: checkpoint starting: immediate force wait flush-all
2016-01-12 22:23:34 UTC::@:[2445]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 23 buffers (0.0%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.005 s, sync=0.011 s, total=0.051 s; sync files=20, longest=0.011 s, average=0.000 s
2016-01-12 22:23:35 UTC::@:[2445]:LOG: checkpoint starting: immediate force wait
2016-01-12 22:23:35 UTC::@:[2445]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 0 buffers (0.0%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.001 s, sync=0.000 s, total=0.005 s; sync files=0, longest=0.000 s, average=0.000 s
2016-01-12 22:25:20 UTC::@:[2445]:LOG: checkpoint starting: force wait
2016-01-12 22:25:24 UTC::@:[2445]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 32 buffers (0.1%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=3.133 s, sync=0.015 s, total=3.161 s; sync files=27, longest=0.015 s, average=0.000 s
2016-01-12 22:30:20 UTC::@:[2445]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2016-01-12 22:30:20 UTC::@:[2445]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.001 s, sync=0.004 s, total=0.018 s; sync files=1, longest=0.004 s, average=0.004 s
----------------------- END OF LOG ----------------------
```

The "Alarms and Recent Events" panel on the web GUI say:

```
time (utc-5)    event
Jan 12 5:29 PM
Finished DB Instance backup
Jan 12 5:25 PM
Backing up DB instance
Jan 12 5:24 PM
DB instance created
```

Comment: This question has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709153/disabling-aws-rds-backups-when-creating-updating-instances) at StackOverflow

Answer (score 3):

Set up your maintenance and backup window in the RDS instance control panel. Some information is available [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AdjustingTheMaintenanceWindow.html).

This "backup on creation" behavior isn't documented anywhere I can see. It may be automatic and not able to be changed.

Why are you creating so many databases or stopping / starting database so often that it matters? Some context could make it easier to help you. I created my RDS database once, it's backed up nightly in my backup window.

Comment: Does this mean I have to disable backup on creation?

Comment: I think you can change your backup window any time you want. I don't know why you'd have to disable backup on creation.

Comment: The only options I see on the page you linked are for "Disabling Automatic Backups" and "Enable Automatic Backups". Ctrl-F "window" doesn't even find anything. What do you mean maintenance and backup window?

Comment: Link and text updated (5 seconds on Google).